# Redirect urls different domain endings

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, cpanel

I need to redirect WWW and non-WWW domain to different domain ending. Both domains are on the same cPanel.

How do I do that via `.htaccess`? This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.abc\.co\.nz\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you searched the web? Have you searched this site? Have you tried anything? Why didn't it work for you? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have and that is what I got:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.abc\.co\.nz\/" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to redirect. But for example if you wanted to redirect a page called abc to a website: def.com you would use:

`redirect 301 /abc http://def.com`

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thnanks but not really. I need to rewrite all pages from domain.com to domain.co.nz

Answer (score 0):

In that case then all you need to do is put this code in your .htaccess of domain.com:

`redirect 301 / http://domain.co.nz`

This will redirect any part of domain.com to domain.co.nz